# Combine all known ML algorithms into one through Bayes

Tags: machine-learning

Let there be an infinite series of pieces of data we want to predict. Take the set of all algorithms ("hypotheses") ML has discovered; different hyper-parameters count as another algorithm. Give each algorithm a score ("relative prior probability") of 2^(-number of bits to specify algorithm, still including hyper-parameters). For each piece of data, ask each algorithm to predict its value, then reveal the true value. Multiply each algorithm's score by the probability it assigned to the true value. (For probabilities, renormalize.)

Under what assumptions does this converge to the highest-scoring algorithms predicting correctly? If one of the algorithms knows enough about the series to give the best-scoring possible answer, this will converge. If the series is generated by predicting our algorithm and using the data that favors the underdog, this won't converge.

Why isn't there a tool out there that approximates this to let people build classifiers without knowing what algorithms and hyper-parameters to use, if they accept an initial period of overfitting? How long would that period be?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a practical algorithm. *Boosting* is a more practical implementation of some aspects of this suggestion.  The rest sounds like the universal probability distribution of Kolmogorov complexity theory.

Comment: What do mean by "the set of all algorithms ML has discovered"?  Since there are infinitely many possible algorithms, when do you propose that your approach should terminate?  What do you mean by "converge"?  What do you mean by "the highest-scoring algorithms predicting correctly"?  Do you mean, will it find the algorithm whose score (after multiplying by the probabilities it assigns to the outcomes) is the largest possible?  What do you mean by "generated by predicting our algorithm and using the data that favors the underdog"?

Comment: Have you heard of regularization?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4961/2921, http://hunch.net/?p=36

Comment: You're describing an impossible version of Bayesian model averaging.